# How to use custom roles in spring webflux security?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-webflux

I have followed [blog](https://medium.com/@ard333/authentication-and-authorization-using-jwt-on-spring-webflux-29b81f813e78) for Spring Webflux and JWT for building basic REST API with authentication and authorization.

Step1: 
Token generation api is working correctly with role which I have tested in [JWT](http://jwt.io).

Step2:  With Token when I am trying to access any REST API which is not giving result, giving error below:

```
{
    "timestamp": 1564685146747,
    "path": "/api/user/getallusers",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "No enum constant com.example.learn.constant.Role.USER",
       "trace": "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant com.example.learn.constant.Role.USER\r\n\tat java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Unknown Source)\r\n\tat org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.getPotentiallyConvertedSimpleRead(MappingMongoConverter.java:944)\r\n\tat 
org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1495)\r\n\tat ...."
}
```

Rest controller is :

```
 @RestController
    public class UserController {

        @Autowired
        private UsersRepository userRepository;


         // this api is not working 
        @RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/getallusers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        public Flux<Users> getAllUsers() {
                  System.out.println("COMINING"); // ok
            return userRepository.findOneByEmail("user1@learning.com");
        }


        // while this api is working
        @RequestMapping(value = "/api/user/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
        public Mono<ResponseEntity<?>> users() {

            return Mono.just(ResponseEntity.ok(new Message("data")));
        }
       // Response : { content:"data" }
    }
```

Comment: @dur thanks. now i am able to access other authorized resource using token. initially, i was not understanding the error. it was looking same role in db as in enum declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Spring per default will apply the prefix `ROLE_` to all roles used.

If you have a custom role like `ADMIN` you will have to in the `@PreAuthorize` use `ROLE_ADMIN`

Comment: I tried to like this but no success.

Comment: please tell what success you didn't have, what problems did you face, what does the debug server log say, more information please than just `no success`

Comment: please post your security configuration and all relevant security classes like AuthenticationManager and UserDetailsService

Comment: you database roles should be `USER` and your role enum should be `Role.USER` while the `@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")` should be like that with the prefix

Comment: You have still not answered any of the questions, are the roles stored as ”ROLE_USER” in the database because that is wrong. Your code is very messy and hard to follow. You are coding imperatively and not using the powers of Mono/Fluxes and there is already a built in JWT filter in spring if you read the documentation. The error medsage is telling you that your rolennames are wrong

Comment: Thank you for your valuable inputs. the problem was in ROLE,  in the database and Role enum both were not matching.  so your third comments helped. 
whatever i learnt , I will upload the whole code on git repo.